# Where do I put Java Dependencies to run crawler4j-2.2.jar?

Tags: java, search

I'm new to Java and aren't sure where to place the Java Dependencies which are required to run  crawler4j. Do I put them in the same folder, or do I put them where Java is located on my machine, or what? Please help me.

Comment: There is apparently ambiguity in your question. Are you asking this question because you can't manage to run it (i.e. you're having classpath problems) or because you'd like to know what's the normal practice (i.e. to avoid unforeseen problems)? I think that it's the later. But just to be sure :)

Answer (score 1):

Putting the dependent JARs in the same folder as your application JAR / bytecode files is a reasonable approach.  As others mention, you need to ensure that the actual folder containing the JARs is on the classpath when the JVM is launched to run the application.  The `-cp` argument is the recommended way to do this, and it is common practice to create a little shell script / batch file to launch the app with the appropriate JVM parameters.

Putting them into the Java installation is not a good idea for a couple of reasons.

- It might have unforeseen side-effects on other applications run using that installation.  This includes applications run by other users.
- It will make upgrading your Java installation to the next patch level more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put them on the CLASSPATH.  If you're running your/the application from the command line you can specify your classpath using the -cp argument for java

Answer (score 0):

You put them in your classpath. The classpath can be specified with the `-cp` argument when you run the java program.

`java -cp depend1.jar;depend2.jar;etc...  Class2Run`